# Unable To Insert An Array Selection into a Database

Tags: javascript, android, nullpointerexception

First off, I would just like to mention that my problem isn't as easy as the title suggests. Here is my problem. Basically I am trying to set the value of a string to a randomly selected item in a string array. Shown here:

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.states);
selected_state = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
```

When a button is pushed, this string is insert into my database. Like this:

```
long id = database_helper.insertData(selected_state);
```

It seem like it should work, but unfortunately for me it does not. Apparently selected_state is null when I try to insert it. But another string in my app that is pulled from an editText and inserted the exact same way is totally fine. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
public class my_class extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
View rootView;
Button bing;
EditText text;
public String  selected_state;
public String TEXT;
DatabaseAdapter database_helper;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    bing = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
    text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_edit);
    String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.states);
    selected_state = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
    bing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            send();
        }

        private void send() {
            TEXT = text.getText().toString();
            //VALUE HOLDS UP TO HERE
            long id = database_helper.insertData(TEXT, selected_state);//NULL!!!!!!
            if(id<0){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SHES STUCK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SHES IN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                text.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


}
}
```

Thanks everyone!

**EDIT** The string (or what I believe to be a string) value has been carried down to the same place TEXT is. Marked above

Comment: Have you attached a debugger to see what the values of array are?

Comment: I did. The line I get the Null Pointer on is this: `long id = database_helper.insertData(TEXT, selected_state);`

Comment: TEXT is fine, and selected_state is fine up to the line before, so is id null?

Comment: **Update** I never initialized database helper. I just did, but I am still getting the nullPointer on the same line.

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace of your error?